# Can I put an HTTP proxy service in my java app to intercept all HTTP requests and change the headers?

Tags: java, android, http

I am writing an android app in java, and would like to intercept all HTTP traffic from its outgoing requests and change the user agent from the header. I know there are tools to do this from separate apps/programs like Charles' Proxy, but can I do this from within the app itself? Would I be able to register a service in my app for this? If so, do you have any links I can reference to get started or have any tips? I am a novice coder, so anything at all is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use OkHttp to make requests? If so, the library has a powerful mechanism of interceptors to do exactly what you want.

Comment: I do not use OkHttp to make the requests. I am using an external API where I do not have the capability to build the headers myself. This is why I need to intercept them with a proxy.